# Continuous limits

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

How can I show $f:[a,b] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is increasing implies it is left continuous on $(a,b)$?

My attempt:

Case 1: $f(a)=f(b)$

Trivial case, it is a constant continuous function so it is left continuous.

Case 2: $f(a)<f(b)$

I am stuck. Where can I start this part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion is not true. Consider the function $f$ which is $0$ on $[0,1/2)$, $f(x) = 1$ for $x \in [1/2,1]$. Then $f$ is not left continuous at $1/2$.

Comment: In your function, lim x->0.5-    f(x)=0. It is left  continuous at 1/2

Comment: In general you say that a function $f:I \to \mathbb R$ is left continuous at $a$ (a point in the interior of $I$) iff the following holds: If $a_n \to a$, $a_n \leq a$,  then $f(a_n) \to f(a)$. See here https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Continuity/Real_Function/Left-Continuous/Point for more details.